# Is it possible to attach a custom trigger to svn command?

Tags: svn

Sometimes I make a change that I later find unnecessary and I run `svn revert` on the file(s). In a minority of cases, I find myself regretting having undone the change and wanting to take a second look.

Is there any way to attach a custom made trigger to an `svn` command, such as `revert` but not limited to, which would, upon execution also run `cp ${file(s)_affected} ${archive_dir}` so that I have the change archived for at least some time and that I don't have to run the command separately? Sort of like having a DB trigger that, upon row deletion from one table, copies it to another or does something else without the user having to perform the action separately.

Answer (score 1):

There is no facility for this built into Subversion itself.

However, since you're working in a command shell environment you can implement any functionality you want. Create a shell script or alias in your profile which takes precedence over the `svn` executable. For the commands you wish to "override" or institute these additional protections, implement your own functionality which wraps the standard `svn` function.